# How to use busybox dd command to flash an image in windows

Tags: windows, busybox, dd

I am trying to write an companion application for windows and Mac OS/X that will flash an embedded Linux OS to an microsd card with a single click. I would like to use busybox's dd command to do this. I have tried to use the windows port of this, but it crashes on windows 10. Here are few reason's why I would like to do it this way.

- The users of these devices are not technical, so it will need to be one click for ease of use.
- The installer needs to be portable and packaged together in a way where it can run off of an USB.

Currently, I have been trying to run these commands in windows:

```
busybox dd bs=4M if=\path\to\img of=e:
busybox dd bs=4M if=\path\to\img of=\\.\e:
```

Both of these return errors.
Does anyone know of a way i can use busybox dd to flash an image to an sdcard specifically in windows?

Comment: You might want to try on http://serverfault.com.

Comment: It would typically be preferable for your application to directly write to the device rather than shelling out to a third-party utility.

Comment: @Harry Johnston. I agree that having the application directly write would be the preferred method, I am on a time crunch to meet a deadline. This is why I was hoping to use the dd command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are multiple ports of dd for windows and they all behave slightly different.

This is the one I'm using and it works flawlessly in Windows 10 using the `\\.\E:` syntax: http://www.chrysocome.net/dd

However, it needs to run with elevated rights ("as admin"), otherwise it isn't allowed low-level access to devices.

---

(Probably not relevant for you, but maybe for others: Be careful, this dd version offers a "special" kind of interpretation of `\\?\` which is very confusing. Normally, `\\?\` can be used to turn off the path validation of the Win32 subsystem, so you can access all objects in the `\??` namespace of the kernel object manager, including `GLOBALROOT`, so in order to access the kernel path `\Device\something` you would use `\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\something`. Here, dd parses these kinds of paths manually and *directly* interprets them as kernel object manager paths, so you would need to use `\\?\Device\something` with dd!)